# Checking if two characters are the same using == (Java)

Tags: java, string, char, charat

I am trying to check if two characters are equal in a while loop but get this error when I run it:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
    at Practice.main(Practice.java:27)

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("String: ");
        String firstIndex = input.next();
        System.out.print("String Two: ");
        String secondIndex = input.next();

        int seqStart = -1;
        int secCheck = 0;
        int start;

    if (firstIndex.length() >= secondIndex.length()) {
        for (int firstCheck = 0; firstCheck <= firstIndex.length(); firstCheck++) {
            if (firstIndex.charAt(firstCheck) != secondIndex.charAt(0)) {
                continue;
            }else if (firstIndex.charAt(firstCheck) == secondIndex.charAt(0)) {
                start = firstCheck;
                while (firstIndex.charAt(firstCheck) == secondIndex.charAt(secCheck)) {
                    for (int check = 0; secCheck < secondIndex.length(); check++) {
                        firstCheck++;
                        secCheck++;
                        if (check == secondIndex.length()) {
                            seqStart = start;
                            secCheck = (secondIndex.length() + 10);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
System.out.println(seqStart);     
    }
}
```

The program is supposed to check if one String is contained within another and if so, it returns the location of where the second String started in the first. If not, it returns -1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `firstCheck <= firstIndex.length()` should be `firstCheck < firstIndex.length()` - Java is (mostly) zero indexed

Comment: did that but I am still getting an error on the 27th line which is: while (firstIndex.charAt(firstCheck) == secondIndex.charAt(secCheck)) {

Comment: `while (firstIndex.charAt(firstCheck) == secondIndex.charAt(secCheck))` - What happens if there are no matching `char`s?

Comment: it works fine, returns -1

Comment: But after the `for-loop` has completed, what are `firstCheck` and `secCheck` set to?  You need to check the state of these variables...`while (firstCheck < firstIndex.length() && secCheck < secondIndex.length() && firstIndex.charAt(firstCheck) == secondIndex.charAt(secCheck)) {`

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop says this:

```
for (int firstCheck = 0; firstCheck <= firstIndex.length(); firstCheck++)
```

The problem is that middle statement, `firstCheck <= firstIndex.length()`. The loop will run with `firstCheck` equal to `firstIndex.length()`. Then, when you use `firstIndex.charAt(firstCheck)`, it will be out of range, because strings are zero-indexed, so there's no character at the position equal to the length of the string. You can fix that like this:

```
for (int firstCheck = 0; firstCheck < firstIndex.length(); firstCheck++)
```

Comment: I did that but I am still getting an error on the 27th line which is: while (firstIndex.charAt(firstCheck) == secondIndex.charAt(secCheck)) {

Comment: Alex’s MacBook Pro:Desktop Alex$ javac Practice.java
Alex’s MacBook Pro:Desktop Alex$ java Practice
String: hello
String Two: ell
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
 at Practice.main(Practice.java:27)
Alex’s MacBook Pro:Desktop Alex$

Comment: @AlexSmadja `secCheck` is going out of bounds. I'm not sure what you're trying to do there, but the nested loops without resetting it are making it go out of bounds.

Comment: What's making it go out of bounds? I just started programming so I'm still not great at it. What I'm trying to do is have it check that the letters are continuously matching until check has reached the length of the second String